# Readable and educational implementations of a CPU in a HDL

Tags: microprocessor, fpga, softcore, verilog, vhdl

Can you recommend a readable and educational implementation of a CPU in VHDL or Verilog? Preferably something well documented.

P.S. I know I can look at `opencores`, but I'm specifically interested in stuff people have actually looked at and found interesting.

P.S.2. Sorry about the sucky tags, but as a new user I can't create new ones

Comment: Here's a great blog from a guy trying to create a tiny CPU for a CPLD http://www.stevechamberlin.com/cpu/

Comment: HDL ⊕ Readable, unfortunately.

Comment: @Joby Taffey: link is broken, is this what you meant? http://www.bigmessowires.com/cpu-in-a-cpld/

Comment: [mor1kx](https://github.com/openrisc/mor1kx), a Verilog implementation of OpenRISC 1000. It has some comments. OpenRISC has the advantage that it has a toolchain but is still relatively simple.

Answer (score 18):

You may enjoy an article series I wrote on this long ago for Circuit Cellar magazine,
[Building a RISC System in an FPGA](http://fpgacpu.org/xsoc/cc.html).

Happy hacking!

Comment: See also my Design Con paper, Designing a Simple FPGA-Optimized RISC CPU and System-on-a-Chip [http://fpgacpu.org/papers/soc-gr0040-paper.pdf], which presents the annotated Verilog source code for an FPGA CPU and SoC.

Comment: thats a dead link :/

Comment: Delete the trailing ]?

Answer (score 7):

Get [this](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~hamblen/book/bookse.htm) book, I've got the first edition. A few years ago I implemented their CPU in a little Flex 10K10 FPGA on a PCB I designed, with a couple of push buttons and a single 7-segment display for entering data and displaying the results.

Answer (score 7):

A lot depends on what is your purpose of studying the code? In other words, what does *interesting* mean to you?

If you are doing it in order to see how much complexity can go into a CPU, you may be more interested in studying the source of [OpenSPARC](http://www.opensparc.net/) architectures. It will take a long time to dive in but you will get an appreciation for the overall **big picture** view of a complex microprocessor.

Then, if it is to study specific computer microarchitecture features, you will want to look at some straightforward RISC machines like the [AEMB](http://www.aeste.my/aemb), a small and fast **multi-threaded** 32-bit RISC processor (shameless plug).

Then, if what you want is to learn good coding styles and conventions, the LEON2 design is a good place to learn good VHDL coding style.

However, if your purpose in studying a processor is to learn how to design one yourself, your best bet would be to start with one of the simple 8-bit machines (there are many AVR, 8051, PIC examples on the net).

Comment: Shameless plug - [AEMB](http://github.com/aeste/aemb) - my own "littlest processor that could."

Answer (score 5):

You may try examining some Forth CPU designs. Forth is a simple programming language whose specification and implementation is defined by means of two stacks stack (one for data and one for return addresses).

Several small VHDL/Verilog processors are freely available:

- http://www.ultratechnology.com/4thvhdl.htm
- http://www.jwdt.com/~paysan/b16.html
- http://www.jwdt.com/~paysan/4stack.html
- http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~phwl/mt/public/archives/old/msl16/msl16.html

Some more links can be found here:

- http://www.ultratechnology.com/chips.htm

PS. Despite Forth being a fairly old and obscure language many modern stack-based VMs (Java, fast JavaScript VMs) have similar low-level design so learning about it can be fruitful.

Answer (score 2):

PicoBlaze is nice, however it is not available in vendor-independent VHDL.

Some other choices are:

- A Picoblaze clone in Verilog (you should be able to find this easily). Not sure if it is maintained
- Gumnut is a nice small core supported by a recent Ashenden book.
- The tiny register machine/computer by Thacker (about 200 lines of Verilog)
- Jan Gray's XSoC/XR16 (already mentioned here)

Also, if you are looking for a compiler for your CPU, it is most probable to get one for a 16-bit CPU. Once there was Poderico's compiler from a C-like language to Picoblaze but it has been taken off the web.

Comment: If you include a blank line before your list your answer will be formatted much better.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at the Xilinx [PicoBlaze](http://www.xilinx.com/ipcenter/processor_central/picoblaze/picoblaze_user_resources.htm) processor. It's a minimal 8-bit embedded microcontroller, and the source code should be available.

Comment: That's all structural VHDL though, so not great as a teaching tool

Answer (score 1):

Too late, however I provide a small answer.

There is a course named [fromNand2Tetris](https://www.nand2tetris.org) from University of Jerusalem, this course is also present on coursera, I built the computer they created in that course. I implemented the language in scheme to be able to see myself how the computer works in the least detail. And I succeeded, the simulator they created in Java cannot do everything I wanted to see.

https://github.com/alinsoar/little-computer